# NodeJs unable to callback AWS Secrets Manager response

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to use AWS Secrets Manager to fetch my RDS credentials,
The Secrets Manager SDK is able to get the Secret properly,
But I am unable to export it back to my calling file.

I have 2 files -
**1. index.js -**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var secretsManager = require('./secrets-manager');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    secretsManager.getDbCredentialFromSecretsManager(function(err,creds) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err, null);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Creds ", creds);
            var connection = mysql.createConnection(creds);

            connection.connect(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                  console.error(err.stack);
                  callback(err,null);
                }
                else{
                    callback(null,connection);
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

**2. secrets-manager.js -**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var constants = require('/opt/nodejs/utils/constants');

module.exports = {
    getRDSCredsFromSM
};

function getRDSCredsFromSM (callback) {
    var response = {};

    let secretName = "secretId";

    var client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
        region: constants.aws.region
    });

    client.getSecretValue({SecretId: secretName}, function(err, data) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err, null);
        }
        else {
            if ('SecretString' in data) {
                let secret = data.SecretString;
                secret = JSON.parse(secret);

                console.log("secret",secret);
                callback(null, secret);
            } else {
                let buff = new Buffer(data.SecretBinary, 'base64');
                let decodedBinarySecret = buff.toString('ascii');
                callback(null, decodedBinarySecret);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I feel there's some mistake from me on Node side,
Which is why the callback isn't working properly,
The Lambda Timesout,
And the logs show nothing in creds variable -

```
console.log("Creds ", creds);
```

Comment: Hi.. were you able to solve this? I am facing this problem right now :)

Comment: @Satya yes got it working, sharing my SM Util.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working code -**

```
let async = require('async');
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');

module.exports = {
    getDbCredentialFromSecretsManager
};

const TAG = '[SECRETS-MANAGER-UTIL->';

function getDbCredentialFromSecretsManager (constants, callback) {
    let response = {};
    const METHOD_TAG = TAG + 'getDbCredentialFromSecretsManager->';

    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            let client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
                region: constants.aws.region
            });

            client.getSecretValue({SecretId: constants.aws.sm}, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(METHOD_TAG,err);
                    callback(err, null);
                }
                else {
                    console.log(METHOD_TAG, 'Secrets Manager call successful');
                    if ('SecretString' in data) {
                        let secret = data.SecretString;
                        secret = JSON.parse(secret);
                        response.user = secret.username;
                        response.password = secret.password;
                        response.host = secret.host;
                        response.database = constants.db.database;
                        callback(null, response);
                    } else {
                        let buff = new Buffer(data.SecretBinary, 'base64');
                        let decodedBinarySecret = buff.toString('ascii');
                        callback(null, decodedBinarySecret);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    ],
    function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(METHOD_TAG, err);
            callback(err, response);
        } 
        else {
            callback(null, response);
        }
    });
}
```